# Writing my version of Array.prototype.flat()

Tags: javascript, flatten

```
var each = function(collection, iterator) {
    if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
      for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        iterator(collection[i], i, collection);
      }
    } else {
      for (var key in collection) {
        iterator(collection[key], key, collection);
      }
    }
  };

  var flatten = function(nestedArray, result) {
    var result = [];

    each(nestedArray, function(element) {
      console.log(element);
      if (!Array.isArray(element)) {
        result.push(element)
      } else {
        flatten(element)
      }
    })
    return result;
  };

flatten([1, 2, [3]]);
```

I'm writing my own version of flatten which should flatten a given array by returning a new array with just the values in one array with no nests. I approached this problem that if an element in the given array is nested that it made sense to me to plug it back into the original function of `flatten`. For example, when my program reaches `[3]` at index 2 for the input then `[3]` gets taken as an argument in flatten where it takes the value of `nestedArray` in the function. It should then iterate over the `nestedArray` object and check if that `element` is an array. In the case of `[3]` by logging each element to the screen I see that `[3]` does enter the `flatten` function and has a value of `3` as a result. That value should get pushed into my `result` variable but I am only getting an output of `[1, 2]`. I don't understand exactly why but I suspect that the result variable that is it being pushed into is not the original result variable that contains all of the previous elements that were pushed?

Comment: Each time you call flatten you’re creating a new result array, hiding the parameter.

Comment: Never mind. I have figured it out - just like I suspected the value `3` gets stored in a separate `result` variable. What I had to do was `result = result.concat(flatten(element))` pushes that value into the original `result` which holds all my other elements. @DaveNewton Yup, just as I suspected. I figured out a working solution. Thanks for responding!